# sql to update multiple cols with non null values from other table

Tags: sql

I have the following table (table1) structure as the result of a select case query

```
server      timestamp   ftpSuccRate httpSuccRate
123.2.3.2   1:00 am     1       null
123.2.3.2   1:00 am     null        0.5
```

I want to update another table's (table 2) that has the following structure with values from table1

```
server      timestamp   ftpSuccRate httpSuccRate
123.2.3.2   1:00 am     1           0.5
```

Basically I want to update ftpsuccrate of table2 with the not null ftpSuccRate value of table1 . Same for httpSuccRate. The join criteria betweent table1 and table2 is server and tiemstamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table2

SET table2.ftpSuccRate = CASE
                              WHEN table1.ftpSuccRat IS NULL TEHN
                                     table2.ftpSuccRate
                              ELSE
                                      table1.ftpSuccRat 
                         END.
table2.httpSuccRate = CASE
                              WHEN table1.httpSuccRate IS NULL TEHN
                                     table2.httpSuccRate 
                              ELSE
                                      table1.httpSuccRate 
                         END


FROM (your case select here) AS table1
WHERE table2.server = table1.server AND table2.timestamp = table1.timestamp
```

Comment: While this technically works, this query is not sufficient because it assumes a one-to-one mapping between IP Address/Timestamp fields and this may not be the case which could potentially result in multiple rows being updated - something the poster may not want.

Comment: actual, he said he wants to update where there is a match, his only matching criteria is server and timestamp which is what he gives in his example.  You are right, without a unique key it will be hard not to update multiple rows, but I am working with the information given.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of unique ID field on table 1 that is also in table 2 (as an FK to table 1) to ensure you can accurately map the data.  Unfortunately, it is not sufficient to just use the IP address and/or timestamp as, the data is not "unique enough" in order to prevent multiple matches (and thus, multiple updates) from being found and performed.

Timestamps are NOT a good way to uniquely identify a match between two tables - this is why SQL gives us PKs and FKs, so we can.